Unity Transparent App Using Windows API, Problem with Activating Click through and disabling it
So I am developing a MS paint but transparent, what I want to happen is if I click the button to paint, I should not be able to interact outside the window, essentially disabling the pass through or click through while keeping the transparency. Currenly I have it working except the part where I need it to disable click through
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TransparentWindow : MonoBehaviour
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, string text, string caption, uint type);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);

    private struct MARGINS
    {
        public int cxLeftWidth;
        public int cxRightWidth;
        public int cyTopHeight;
        public int cyBottomHeight;
    }

    [DllImport("Dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern uint DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS margins);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;

    const uint WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
    const uint WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;

    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);

    const uint LWA_COLORKEY = 0x00000001;
    const uint LWA_ALPHA = 0x00000002;

    private IntPtr hWnd;
    private bool isClickThroughEnabled = true;

    private void Start()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow();

        MARGINS margins = new MARGINS { cxLeftWidth = -1 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, ref margins);

        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        //SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 0, LWA_COLORKEY); // This makes the window transparent but still clickable



        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
#endif

        Application.runInBackground = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(isClickThroughEnabled);
        if (!isClickThroughEnabled)
        {
            // Prevent click-through when not explicitly enabled
            SetClickthrough(false);
            return;
        }
        // Check if the pointer is over a UI element
        bool isOverUI = UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current != null && UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();

        // Check if the pointer is over a 2D collider
        bool isOverCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)) != null;

        // Set click-through only if not interacting with UI or colliders
        SetClickthrough(!(isOverUI || isOverCollider));
    }

    private void SetClickthrough(bool clickthrough)
    {
        if (clickthrough)
        {
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
        else
        {
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED);

        }
    }

    public void EnableClickThrough()
    {
        isClickThroughEnabled = true;
    }

    public void DisableClickThrough()
    {
        isClickThroughEnabled = false;
        SetClickthrough(false); // Ensure click-through is disabled immediately
    }

    public void PaintMode()
    {
        Image targetButton = GameObject.Find("Brush").GetComponent<Image>();
        if (isClickThroughEnabled)
        {
            targetButton.color = new Color(73f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 92f / 255f, 1f);
            DisableClickThrough();
        }
        else
        {
            targetButton.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
            EnableClickThrough();
        }
    }
}


Image of how the app will look like, button to be click to activate and deac.clickability is the bottom one, the paint one
I tried a lot already, changing the SetLayeredWindowAttributes, did not work, I tried removing it, because I saw a source where it is not really necessary and it just make everything that has the alpha of 0 not clickable, I also tried playing with this code block SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT), just layer, just transparent, did not work.

Have you tried ClipCursor? Sounds like what you need.
Otherwise, you could use Cursor.lock to lock the system cursor in the middle and use .visible =false to hide it and then provide your own cursor (perhaps showing some kind of circle radius as well) for painting which you can easily confine using unity api.
